# LaTex: How to change caption on figures from "Figure 1:" to "Figure 1 |"

Tags: latex, caption

I have the following LaTex code below which generates a figure of a histogram:

```
\documentclass[review,12pt]{elsarticle}

\usepackage{lineno,hyperref}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amssymb, lipsum, color}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.8]{Histogram A.jpg}
\caption{Histogram Title}\label{Histogram A}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I have attached a picture of the histogram here:
[image: Histogram A]

The caption on the histogram figure will start with `Figure 1: Histogram Title`. How do I change this to `Figure 1 | Histogram Title`? Ie. how do I replace the colon sign to a pipe sign?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: This will depend on your documentclass, therefore please make a [mre] instead of this code fragment. In most cases the `caption` package is probably the easiest way

Comment: Hi @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, I have updated my question with a minimal reproducible example now. Please advise on how I can change from the colon sign to a pipe sign, many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `caption` package:

```
\documentclass[review,12pt]{elsarticle}

\usepackage{lineno,hyperref}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amssymb, lipsum, color}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator{bar}{\space\textbar\space}
\captionsetup{labelsep=bar}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.8]{example-image-duck}
\caption{Histogram Title}\label{Histogram A}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great many thanks @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz. Love the ducking pic!

Comment: @Leockl You're welcome! The pic is from the `duckuments` package, which is really great for creating MWEs (and has some funny stories)